# Left-aligned text on same line as numbered equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I currently have this:

[image: image from example code]

With the following code and preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\backslash c_{t}$ \begin{equation}
{C_{t}: \pi D_{1}U(c_{t},L_{t})+\pi(-1)p_{t}=0 \iff D_{1}U(c_{t},L_{t})-p_{t}=0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I want to have the "`\c_t`" on the same line, left-aligned.

I have tried my best to Google around but nothing seems to be right. One person suggested I put it in a table, but that seems cumbersome, especially to do this numerous times.

Comment: Why the `\backslash c_{t}`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of `\backslash c_{t}` here ( a special notation?) but I would use an `alignat` environment and either `\text{\textbackslash} ...}` or `\backslash...` if this is needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibston.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
\text{\textbackslash} c_{t} &\quad &{}C_{t}: \pi D_{1}U(c_{t},L_{t})+\pi(-1)p_{t} &{}=0 \iff D_{1}U(c_{t},L_{t})-p_{t}&{}=0 \label{foo} \\
\backslash c_{t} &\quad &{}C_{t}: \pi D_{1}U(c_{t},L_{t})+\pi(-1)p_{t} &{}=0 \iff D_{1}U(c_{t},L_{t})-p_{t}&{}=0 \label{fooother} 
\end{alignat}

In \eqref{foo} we see

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The 'text' is only left of the equation, I know. If it should be aligned to the left margin, this is not the solution, however

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Indeed the /ct would ideally be further to the left. I should have deleted the "Ct:" in my submission...here it is redundant. The / ct is a notation meaning "with respect to". Just above this I have a giant ass Lagrangian, and Im now listing the first order conditions with respect to each variable. The slash is the notation the teachers use so why not...

Anyway, yeah this is very close, but even closer left would be better :S

Comment: @goverton2: See the link above of your post. It's far more difficult and I could only copy code from their posts.